# Eclipse Oxygen with pydev has wrong index, cannot rebuild it

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have installed pydev on eclipse oxygen, and globally search the content by pressing "Ctrl+H", but the search result has wrong line numbers, I cannot get correct search result either by doing "Refresh" or re-creating the workspace, anyone has come into the same situation and help me ? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have auto-build turned on (in the menu: project > build automatically)?

You can also trigger a reindex by doing the following: open a PyDev editor, trigger: `Ctrl+2` and then choose `--reindex` in the menu that opens (considering you're doing a search in the PyDev tab).

Comment: I have auto-build turned on. The reindex works! But I have to trigger the reindex several times to get the full correct results...